# Is it possible to find files by the exact date then execute tar command on the results files?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, grep

I want to search for files by the exact date and then execute tar command on the results files.

Example:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1      0 Dec  4 08:07 file-1
-rw-rw-r--  1      0 Dec  4 08:07 file-2
-rw-rw-r--  1      0 Dec  5 08:07 file-3
```

I want to get only files with Dec 4 date and passing them to the tar command.

The archive should contain:

```
tar -ztvf dec4.tar.gz
```

Output:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1      0 Dec  4 08:07 file-1
-rw-rw-r--  1      0 Dec  4 08:07 file-2
```

This is my script it is still copying those Dec 5.

ls -ltr ./ | grep "Dec  4" | tar -zcvf /home/backupfiles_$(date '+%Y_%m_%d' --date='1 days ago').tar.gz

Comment: Need more info, like... what have you tried to make this work the way you want it to?

Comment: there bro. can you help me for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stat -c"%z;%n" * | grep '^2012-12-04' | awk -F';' '{ print $2 }' | xargs tar -zcvf dec4.tar.gz
```

Comment: You're welcome. I think bishop's solution is way better, but apparently not every linux distro has find with -newermt key support out of the box. If you have spaces in filenames modify awk part a bit: `awk -F';' -vq='"' '{ print q $2 q }'`

Comment: btw bro can u explain to me your script? :)

Comment: stat - file statistics, * - any file and folder (same as ./*), -c - user format, %z - modification date, %n - file name, `awk '{ print $2 }'` - print second column -F - field separator, xargs takes lines from stdin and uses it as arguments to any command, in our case `tar -zcvf`. Run `stat --help` `xargs --help` `awk --help` for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
  ls -l ./ | grep "Dec 4" | tar -cvf archive.tar --null -T /dev/stdin
```

**EDIT** : use a temp file to store file names:

```
ls -l | grep "Dec  4" | tr -s " " "#" | cut -d "#"  -f 9 >tempfile ; tar -T tempfile -cvf arch.tar ; rm -r tempfile
```

Comment: it has an error... when tar -ztvf dec4.tar.gz
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors

Comment: try the sort format:
ls -l ./ | grep "Dec 4" | tar -cvf archive.tar

Comment: ls -l ./ | grep "Dec 4" | tar -cvf archive.tar --null -T /dev/stdin - is fine bro but when i view the tar file "tar -ztvf dec4.tar.gz" it says "stdin: not in gzip format tar: Child returned status 1 tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors"

Comment: that depends of the compression method , use this command to open the archive : tar -xvf archive.tar

Comment: it is still copying those Dec 5 bro.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -name "*" -newermt 2013-12-04 ! -newermt 2013-12-05 | xargs -I {} tar -czvf files.tar.gz {}
```

Note: This will tar only the files not the directory hierarchy. You can specify your required date in find command.

Comment: invalid predicate `-newermt'

Comment: I hope its a valid switch in linux find command. -newerXY (where X and Y can be specific modifier inside newer). This worked fine for me. Verify whether your using the complete supported "find" or the one comes with busybox applet. Please check "man find".

Comment: NAME
       find - search for files in a directory hierarchy

SYNOPSIS
       find [path...] [expression]

DESCRIPTION
       This  manual  page documents the GNU version of find.   find searches the directory tree rooted at each given
       file name by evaluating the given expression from left to right, according to the rules of  precedence  (see
       section  OPERATORS),  until  the  outcome is known (the left hand side is false for and operations, true for
       or), at which point find moves on to the next file name.

Comment: i dont have a "newerXY" :(

Comment: ***Do not use this code***  I just lost a bunch of files to it.  This command runs tar once for each file you want, but the 'c' option tells tar to delete the existing tar and Create a new one with just the one file.  So at the end you have a tar with only the last file in it.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to tar files that are modified on a certain date?  If so, that's a specific instance of the general problem "[taring files modified between two dates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72156)".  So like:

```
find /path/to/files/ \
   -newermt 20131204 -not -newermt 20131205 -type f -print0 \
   | cpio --create --null  --format=ustar \
   | gzip > /tmp/dec-4.tar.gz
```

This handles the case of many files, files that have spaces in the names, and avoids issues of grep including files that have a date in the name.

Comment: uname -a, tar -v, find -v -- give us some versions to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to overloop! :) this is my script!

```
stat -c"%z;%n" * | grep '^2013-12-04' | grep "file-*" | awk -F';' '{ print $2 }' | xargs tar -zcvf pjpj.tar.gz
```